# Subprocess.Popen system can't find the file

Tags: subprocess, popen

I'm not sure why subprocess can't find my file. I keep getting this error

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
file= r'C:\Users\NIA\Desktop\2.py'
x = 'python' + file + str(7) + str(8)

process = subprocess.Popen([x], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

if stderr:
    print stderr
else:
    print stdout
```

Comment: you should print var *x*: it is not what you want it to be, there is no whitespace between the components. You should pass as a list: [ 'python', file, str(7), str(8)], see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: Awesome, your suggestion works! Thank you!

Comment: A little extra: you can add the directory on where do you want to do the command with `cwd`: `subprocess.Popen(["python", "2.py", str(7), str(8)], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell = True, cwd= " C:\users\NIA\Desktop\")`

Comment: @GuiGWR great tip, this helps a lot. Thanks!